# PopUpViewController won't pop up more then once. SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, popup, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have `PopUpViewControllerSwift` which I want to pop up time after time until the an `alreadyMatched` index reaches zero. This is how I am performing the pop up, code:

```
var alreadyMatched = [0,1,2]   

class QuestionsGame: UIViewController {

         var popUpViewController = PopUpViewControllerSwift()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       matched()
}


    func matched() { 

        var a = alreadyMatched.count   
        if a > 0 {

            self.view.addSubview(self.popUpViewController.view)
            self.addChildViewController(self.popUpViewController)
            self.popUpViewController.setValues(UIImage(named: "hot.png"), messageText: "You have matched!!", congratsText: "Snap!")
            self.popUpViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            alreadyMatched.removeLast()
            }
        }
}
```

and the `PopUpViewControllerSwift`code is:

```
@objc class PopUpViewControllerSwift : UIViewController {

    var popUpUserImage: UIImageView!
    var messageLabel: UILabel!
    var popUpView: UIView!
    var congratsLabel: UILabel!
    var matchedOrNot = 2

    var matchedUser : PFUser!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func setValues(image : UIImage!, messageText : String, congratsText : String) {
        self.popUpUserImage!.image = image
        self.messageLabel!.text = messageText
        self.congratsLabel.text = congratsText
    }

    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        });
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
            }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                if (finished)
                {
                    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                      let questionsVC =   sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") as! QuestionsGame
                      questionsVC.timer()

                }
        })
    }
}
```

For some reason this will only pop up one time, no repeatedly? I am sure it is something to do with the ParentViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Your first instance of `QuestionsGame` is showing in the screen. In viewDidLoad, you execute `matched()` and put the view of your popover in this instance, which shows the popover. This works correctly.

Now the part where you want to show it again: You have a button creating a **new** instance of `QuestionsGame` with the code:

```
let questionsVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") as! QuestionsGame
```

you accessed `matched()` manually again (which results it in being called twice, one in viewDidLoad and one manually) This method will put the view of your popover in the **new** instance, but you won't see all this because the **new** instance is not in view.

EDIT:

If you want to create a new popup, using a delegate would be a simple way of doing it. I've explained the use of a delegate in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586281/how-to-pass-data-in-conditional-unwind-segue/29586805#29586805). I'm not sure how you are dismissing your popover though, but that's another problem. If you want to create a new popover within your popover, you can use a delegate to access the method `matched()` so the new popover will be shown on top of your current view.

Comment: Sorry thats not correct. a will be 3, but then using the `alreadyMatched.removeLast()` will make it become 2. Which is still more then 0. The if statement runs fine, the problem is the view controller will not run more then once.

Comment: No because if you read the code, the function `matched()` is called again once the popUpViewController is removed from the view, there for repeating the process until the count reaches 0. no for in loop is needed.

Comment: Hmm, didn't read the code of your popover class. You really should remove code thats not relevant to your question (and fix the markup). Makes it more readable for people to help you.

Comment: the popUpViewController is very relevant, its the cause and problem to why it's not working.

Comment: the problem is to do with how the popUpViewController is being called and made childViewController. I think?

Comment: You are telling me all the code in ur PopupViewController is relevant?

Comment: Maybe not all, I have simplified slightly.

Comment: So I've used the search function to find where you've used `matched()`. Thats when the playagain button is pressed no? I think the problem lies in calling the method `matched()`. You're making a new instance of `QuestionsGame` and putting the view of your popup in that new instance, while the new instance of `QuestionsGame` is not in view.

Comment: Yes it is inside the playAgain Button. why would the questionsGame not be in view? the popUpViewController is just animated over the top right? then it is removed? then I am trying to show it again.

Comment: Ahh Ok, its starting to make more sense now. So this is the answer, but what is the solution? how might I write the code so it will work?

Comment: updated again, if you want we can start a chat so we won't make to many comments.

Comment: I still think that hasnt solved the problem, as I have now called the `matched()` function like this: `var questionsGameVC = QuestionsGame()
        questionsGameVC.matched()` and still nothing happenes, although the function is being called as `println` statements are being printed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75595/discussion-between-jacobson-talom-and-henry-brown).